# How to add a listener event to a seek bar in android studio using kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I tried this but getting error because the function myListener should return something.

what I want to do is to get the seek bar value each time I'm changing it's value at runtime and assign the value to another variable name counter.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val seek = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBar)
    var flashLightStatus: Boolean = false
    val counter = 0;



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(myListener())

        startFlashLight()
    }

    private fun myListener(): SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener? {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the function `onProgressChanged`

```kotlin
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
    object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            // Log.d("seekbar", "Your Progress: ${seekBar?.progress}"   
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) = Unit
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code and listen value change runtime

```
     seekBarView.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onStopTrackingTouch: ")
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {

            }

           
            override fun onProgressChanged(
                seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int,
                fromUser: Boolean
            ) 
                  // here 

        })
```